# How to handle caching when having multiple React.js component instances with data requests?

Tags: javascript, caching, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I'm working on a project where on the same page I have multiple React components.
Some of them are making the same web service call

When I run the app I find that this service call is made twice or even more depends on the number of instances

What I want is to make this call once and cache it, and whenever any component wants this data they can read it from the store cache.

I tried to set some sort of a flag that whether the data is fetched or not, but because that all of the instances are loaded at the same time they all see the flag with the initial value

Code:
In the component code I have this:

```
class WeightCharts extends React.Component {
componentWillMount() {
    const Component = this;
    this.state = {
        weight: null
    }
    AppActions.getWeight();

}
```

Please note: `AppActions.getWeight()` which is the data fetching action

So if I have for example 3 instances of `<WeightCharts />` a 4 calls will be made

My proposed solutions:
1- Passing this data as a props from a top level component but then the component will be heavily dependant on a parent component

2- In the component I may try to get the data from the store and if the store didn't find the data in the cache it should trigger the fetch action
But as far as I understand triggering an action from a store is anti pattern

My project is an open source if you want to take a deeper look:
https://github.com/muhammad-saleh/weightlyio

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe you can try to find the data somewhere and trigger Action upon the result. Store will listen to your corresponding actions and update it's data.

Comment: What do you mean with 'try to find the data' and what do you mean with somewhere ?
the caching can be done in the store but I can't trigger action from there

Comment: In your WeightSource file, after fetching, you can call an Actions.getWeightSuccess() which should dispatch the corresponding ActionType(such as GET_WEIGHT). Register your Store to listen to that ActionType and save the fetched data. after saving, your Store emits the changes. Your React components which listen to the Store will be updated.

Comment: But there's no sources in FLUX it's just how alt.js works also the only purpose of the sources is to return promises and not to do anything else

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for pointing it out. I'm not familiar with Alt. My suggestion is : If the Component get no data from the store, the React component should trigger the action which will fetch and update the store. React components and Actions are 2 places you can trigger actions regard to your application.

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at https://github.com/facebook/dataloader

> DataLoader is a generic utility to be used as part of your application's data fetching layer to provide a simplified and consistent API over various remote data sources such as databases or web services via batching and caching.